# Downloading .NET 4 source code

Tags: .net, download

I've been trying to download the source code for .NET 4 (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) since yesterday but it just doesn't work.

Clicking on the download links in IE, FF does refresh the page but the download doesn't start.

Clicking on the download links in Chrome does start a download but it's called netframework.aspx, there is no indication of how big the download is. In any event, trying to download with DAP has not result as well.

I've tried this on 2 different machines with the same results. And all of my installations including Windows is kept up to date.

Any suggestions or authentic alternatives would be appreciated.

Comment: Which link are you trying?  Do you have javascript enabled?

Comment: The link against version 4 of .NET. Yes, I do have JavaScript enabled on all browsers. When Chrome starts downloading, I can't even copy-paste the link to a download manager since the link is to the page itself.

Comment: I have all of the source files on my machine, but I have no idea how I got them.  I am almost certain that VS integration is broken with 2010 SP1.  I also don't think MS offers an unpacked download of the source.  I am pretty sure I used NetMassDownloader to get the framework: http://netmassdownloader.codeplex.com/

Comment: NetMassDownloader seems like a good option. I did finally get IE to throw the download to a download manager (DAP) but without indication of its size. Downloading right now. Will revert back if it works.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I've had this happen before many times.  It *is* downloading the installer, it just has the wrong name.  I don't think it's worked properly in months.

You can just change the extension from aspx to msi and then install it.

```
netframework.aspx -> netframework.msi
```

---

IE10 appears to work now, where it didn't before (not sure if this applies to all versions of IE now).

It appears that when you download the file, the webpage is using a postback to `netframework.aspx` and sets an HTTP header to notify the browser of the content.  Note the filename set in the `content-disposition` header which is being ignored by Chrome.

```
Cache-Control:private
content-disposition:attachment; extension-token; filename=DotNET.msi
Content-Type:Application/binary-stream
Date:Fri, 10 May 2013 18:31:05 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-AspNet-Version:2.0.50727
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Comment: +1 I remember now how I got the source files on my machine :).

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft has recently updated .NET Framework Sources website, see this blog post: [A new look for .NET Reference Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/02/24/a-new-look-for-net-reference-source.aspx).

All sources, including project files, can now be downloaded directly: http://referencesource-beta.microsoft.com/download.html No installers, no stupid javascript protection, just a direct link to a ZIP file.

Comment: The answer has already been selected but thank you very much for the update.

Comment: But it seems that links to .net Framework 4 sources (exactly 4.0) have been removed. :-(

Comment: The "A new look..." page contains the cited direct download link. The zip is 50Mb, expanding to over 18000 files and over 260Mb.